# Hiding fields when creating content in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using the "Commerce Auction" module to create auctions from content automatically. I'd like to make it so when the user inputs data, only some fields show up.

I've tried using the field permission module, but it can't hide fields when users are creating new content.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to hide fields from the user when creating new content using the Field Permissions module

http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions

Comment: This only hides the fields after the node is created; they still show up to the author even when they don't have access to view in the module.